# if condition always work inside $(window).resize function

Tags: jquery

I have this script and I want when window is only less than `768px` `console.log('less than 768px');` but my script works always when window is more then `768px` please help me someone  `:(`

```
    var width = $(window).width();
    $(window).on('resize',function(){
        if (width < 768){
            console.log('less than 768px');
        }else{
            console.log('nothing');
        }
    });
```

Comment: ...and where are you getting the value of width?!

Comment: can you post the origine of with value you can use:
var width = document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.body.clientWidth || window.innerWidth;

Comment: If you assign value to `width` only **before** any pages resizes, and never change its value after resize, then there is no wonder you don't get what you want. It's logic error, by the way.

Comment: https://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/06/using-window-matchmedia-to-do-media-queries-in-javascript/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the width inside the resize event callback to get the updated value:

```
$(window).on('resize',function(){
    var width = $(window).width();
    if (width < 768){
        console.log('less than 768px');
    }else{
        console.log('nothing');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the `width` variable inside the `resize` handler, otherwise it only uses the window width as set on page load.

```
$(window).on('resize',function(){
    var width = $(window).width();

    if (width < 768){
        console.log('less than 768px');
    } else {
        console.log('nothing');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This works when set width value

```
$(window).resize(function (){
    var width = document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.body.clientWidth || window.innerWidth;
if (width < 768){
    console.log('less than 768px');
} else{
    console.log('nothing');
}  
})
```

Comment: `var width = $(window).width();` is a little shorter.